# How does Non - local Jumps in C defined in setjmp.h work?

Tags: c, setjmp

The *C Reference Manual*, Appendix B describes two functions `setjmp` and `longjmp` for something called *non-local jumps*. Apart from the basic understanding that `setjmp` saves the state information and longjmp restores the `state`, I haven't been able to understand the exact flow and use cases for this feature.

So, what exactly does this feature accomplish and where is it useful?

Comment: I implemented user mode thread library using setjmp and long jump. No assembly whatsoever the context switchis aachieved by lngjmp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for the control flow: `setjmp` returns twice, and `longjmp` never returns. When you call `setjmp` for the first time, to store the environment, it returns zero, and the when you call `longjmp`, the control flow passes to return from `setjmp` with the value provided in the argument.

(Note that `setjmp` needn't actually be functions; it may well be a macro. `longjmp` is a function, though.)

Use cases are generally cited as "error handling", and "don't use these functions".

Here's a little control flow example:

```
jmp_buf env;

void foo()
{
    longjmp(&env, 10);                      +---->----+
}                                           |         |
                                            |         |
int main()              (entry)---+         ^         V
{                                 |         |         |
    if(setjmp(&env) == 0)         | (= 0)   |         | (= 10)
    {                             |         ^         |
        foo();                    +---->----+         |
    }                                                 +---->----+
    else                                                        |
    {                                                           |
        return 0;                                               +--- (end)
    }
}
```

Notes:

- You cannot pass 0 to `longjmp`. If you do, `1` is returned by `setjmp`.
- You must not return from the function that called `setjmp` before the corresponding `longjmp`. In other words, `longjmp` must only be called *above* `setjmp` in the call stack.
- (Thanks to @wildplasser:) You cannot actually *store* the result of `setjmp`. If you want to return in several different ways, you can use a `switch`, though:

  ```
  switch (setjmp(&env))
  {
  case 0:   // first call
  case 2:   // returned from longjmp(&env, 2)
  case 5:   // returned from longjmp(&env, 5)
  // etc.
  }
  ```

Comment: Wrong. You **should not assign** the "return value" from setjmp(). You may only *evaluate* it.

Comment: @wildplasser: Interesting, do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Googling it ... I came up in c.l.c a few years ago. BRB

Comment: @wildplasser: You're right, it might be forbidden by 7.13.1.1/4 in C11.

Comment: Here is one: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MSC22-C.+Use+the+setjmp%28%29,+longjmp%28%29+facility+securely . Here is a usenet mirror: http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.c/2009-07/msg01601.html

Comment: C99 `An invocation of the setjmp macro shall appear only in one of the following contexts: the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement; one operand of a relational or equality operator with the other operand an integer
constant expression, with the resulting expression being the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement; the operand of a unary ! operator with the resulting expression being the entire controlling expression of a selection or iteration statement; the entire expression of an expression statement (possibly cast to void).`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I really appreciate the effort. But how is this better than a simple function call + return seeing that setjmp has the restriction of not being able to assign the return value?

Comment: @rusticbit: I don't think it's "better"... it's just another tool, and you can use it non-locally, i.e. you can return a long way. It's a little bit like a poor man's C++ exception. (And as the documentation says, you're encouraged *not* to use it.)

Comment: I presume you meant `if( !setjmp(&env)) ... ` ?